# Getting timer from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, android, timer

I'm using javascript for my game timer. I need to pass the time to PHP when the page is called. I tried to pass it in url (ex `timer.php?min =" + mins + "&sec=" +secs`). But it takes too long to display `timer.php` page. It is for android application, when user open the game window, while running in background, the app will send request to the server (`timer.php`) to get the current coutdown. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: How long is it currently taking? and are you opening up a MySql(Or any database) connection in timer.php? If so you may need to rethink the way you store your timer information, as db connections and scripts can typically slow down websites/applications.

Comment: I guess 3-5 seconds. The timer is not connected with the database. It's a server time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you attack this problem from a different perspective.

Let the server send the current time when the page is requested and let javascript simply initiate the clock(the counting down).

so instead of (page sent to browser) ->(request time) -> (return time) ->(update DOMS)

you now have

(page sent to browser with time) -> update DOMS.